# Android support library doesn't exist but can't edit files under "Build" folder to reference Android X

Tags: java, android, android-databinding, androidx

I'm migrating my Android to target 28 and use Android X instead of the Android support libraries. I've changed most of the references in my project to use Android X.

Unfortunately, when I do a build, it complains about the support library reference used in a file under "build" but those are generated and can't be edited.

What am I supposed to do now?

here's the hierarchy of the bug:

```
app/build/generated/source/apt/debug > 
com/company/projectname/databinding/FragmentColorItemBinding.java   > 
error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
```

Obvs, I tried to manually change it but I get this error:

```
Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited.
```

So I can't change it to reference Android X instead.

What can I do to get my build to compile?

It complains on this line btw:

```
public final android.support.v7.widget.CardView colorThumbnail;
```

On that file. I want to use the new CardView but not sure how?

EDIT:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation files('libs/android-binding-v0.6-preview.jar')
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:8.2.0@aar'
    implementation files('libs/ormlite-android-5.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ormlite-core-5.0.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    def appCenterSdkVersion = '2.0.0'
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"

}
```

Comment: Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Have you activated `jetifier`? You need it if you or the dependencies you are using still reference old support lib. Read here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate

Comment: @MichaelStoddart how do I invalidate cache? I did a clean/rebuild and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It doesn't work that way. You have to change more things than what was listed to migrate to AndroidX.

If you are in Android Studio, It is *really* simple to complete the migration process. Just go to `Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX`. Otherwise, you will have to find the `/gradle.properties` file and add these two lines:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

After doing this first part, you need to change the reference in the CardView import statement to the CardView in your java files to this:

```java
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
...
public final CardView colorThumbnail;
```

**Also make sure all the references in your xml files are correct too!**

Comment: I did do refactor > migrate to androidX but it's still giving me that issue. Let me try the gradle.properties solution.

Comment: In migrate to androidx documentation is exactly listed to do both things (migrate and adding the gradle properties)

Comment: I did both and same issue ensues. I"m not sure why but it just doesn't work with the databinding library and cardview.

Comment: Hmm. Can I see the dependency you are using for cardview?

Comment: Wait. I see you haven't changed the reference to the CardView from support to androidx yet, see my edit @Euridice01

Comment: I can't change the reference in the file because it's a file under "Build" and those are generated. Please read the post again. Also, I will edit it to show dependencies.

Comment: I am completely aware of this. There is no point in looking at the build files anyway. You need to review my edit. If the problem persists clean and rebuild your project. @Euridice01

Comment: I did a clean and rebuild, it doesn't work. I did change the cardview references in other parts of my project. For the reference I highlighted above, that code is inside the build file that is generated and that I can't edit. Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Please see my newest edit. You are probably still using the wrong import statement.

Comment: I told you I can't change it FragmentColorItemBinding.java because it's an auto generated file! "Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited." That's the error I get. Do you understand?

Comment: Where are you trying to use CardView? You need to change the reference in _that_ file.

Comment: @Euridice01 Do you understand? You need to change the reference of the import statement in the file you are trying to use CardView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196649/discussion-between-euridice01-and-insurgentpointerexception).